# Weird Unwanted Symmetry during Sculpting

Tags: sculpting

I was doing some sculpting and came across something weird.Even though I am turning off symmetry my sculpts still gets symmetric in such a way that every sculpt has an adjacent deep on their corresponding side(if that makes any sense).The point is if I sculpt using any brush simlar hole is created on the other side corresponding to the mountain I created.I tried changing the brush types but still it doesn't work.Please help.Here's the blend file.

[image]

Comment: Set the X radial value to 1. Just below the mirror axis in the Symmetry/lock part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the symmetry settings, set your radial X parameter to 0. 
[image: Setting X to Zero]